# WPF how to interleave drawing of lines from two separate controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So if control A draws line 1 then draws line 2,

and control B draws line 3 and then line 4.

Is it possible to have control A draw line 1 before control B starts drawing and and then draw line 2 afterwards?

Currently I am using the grid.ZIndex to order the actual controls. But I was wondering if there is any universal WPF draw order property that I could use to interleave the draw order of the lines from two separate controls. Otherwise I am going to have to combine the two controls into one so that I can control the draw order better so that the correct lines end up on top.

```
            <Grid>
              <ControlA Grid.Zindex=1 />
              <ControlB Grid.Zindex=2 />
            </Grid>
```

Comment: So you're looking for like an interwoven plaid type design of lines?

Comment: In your example, ZIndex is redundant - that is how WPF's engine will draw the controls: ControlA and then, overlaid on it, ControlB. As long as the users of these controls keep adding ControlA as a first child and ControlB as a second child of a panel - you should get the results you're looking for. But, if you want to force this structure and not to allow users to change the order - then you should have a third control that combines the two in this structure. May I ask why you have two controls with a visual interaction between them instead of one control?